# Running a C++ Event Loop WITHOUT using QT

Tags: c++, qt, hook, event-loop, mouse-hook

I have been trying to develop a background Windows application in c++ to capture system wide keystrokes and mouse clicks (no I'm not writing a keystroke logger, just keystroke rates!). For this I have figured out that I need to use Windows Hooks and I came across [this excellent video](https://youtu.be/O0C4V6JmlNw) which gave me a basic example. Unfortunately, it uses the QT framework and for licencing (and other time based) reasons, this is not available to me currently. 
 All I need to be able to do is adapt the code so that it does not require the "return a.exec()" line (which I believe is what starts off the event loop).

A comment on the youtube video appeared to have the answer:
"For those who don't use QT, just add 
    while(GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, 0)); 
instead of a.exec(), QT loop. It should work fine"

But could not get this solution to work. Would be very grateful for help in getting the code below to execute as an event loop without depending on the QT framework.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#inlcude <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

HHOOK hHook = NULL;

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM     lParam)
{
    qDebug() << "A Key was pressed";
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv); //need to remove this QT dependency

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc, NULL, 0);
    if (hHook==NULL){
        qDebug() << "Hook Failed";
    }

    return a.exec(); //need to remove this QT dependency
}
```

Here is an attempt (only showing main()) of re-writing using a message loop and removing the QT references:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MSG msg = NULL;
   while (GetMessage(msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)){   
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc, NULL, 0);
    if (hHook==NULL){
        qDebug() << "Hook Failed";
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: [WinAPI message loop](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32Message_Loop00000389.htm) is a bit more complicated. May be the problem is in it.

Comment: You still use QT functions there...

Comment: @Amartel Thanks - will do some further reading on that

Comment: @MarkJansen - not sure if your comment is in reply to my original question or in response to Amartel's comment. If its a response to my original question - read again - the code I put in is an example of what I need to change. This is an example of working code which I need to adapt. I dont know how to make that any clearer.

Comment: I would have expected you to atleast show an attempt at rewriting it using a message loop, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample that works.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

HHOOK g_hHook = NULL;
DWORD g_HookThread;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hookstruct = reinterpret_cast<PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT>(lParam);
    std::cout << hookstruct->vkCode << std::endl;
    if( wParam == WM_KEYUP ) {
        if( hookstruct->vkCode == VK_ESCAPE ) {
            PostThreadMessage( g_HookThread, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL );
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx( g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam );
}

int main()
{
    g_HookThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
    g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL) ) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
    return 0;
}
```

*edit:*
I originally commented that whatpulse switched to directinput, but now they seem to have switched back to lowlevel hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark - I will try this, one thing that confuses me from looking at it though is that there is no main function, so I'm not sure where the entry point is.

Comment: There, i renamed test to main.
Code came straight from my scratch application.

Comment: Superb Mark! This gets me off the ground. Thanks

Comment: P.S. To anyone else who uses Mark's code above. Include these headers:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream>