# Unable to intercept the right-click event

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to intercept the right-click event from the windows with the specific title in Windows, so I decided to use `SetWindowsHookExA` function with the `WH_MOUSE` argument like this:

**Application that launches thus process**

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  HMODULE hook_dll_handle = LoadLibraryA("hook_dll.dll");
  if (hook_dll_handle == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "Unable to load \"hook_dll.dll\". Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  auto mouse_hook = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hook_dll_handle, "mouse_hook");
  if (mouse_hook == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "Unable to get \"mouse_hook\" function's address. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE, mouse_hook, hook_dll_handle, 0);
  if (hook == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "Unable to set hook. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::cin.get();

  if (UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook) == 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Unable to unhook mouse_hook. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

**DLL with the hook function**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
  HMODULE hModule,
  DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
  LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
  switch (ul_reason_for_call)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK mouse_hook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. It hangs the whole explorer.exe or do the other kind of stuff on the different platforms.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a message loop where you have `std::cin.get()` now.

See the Remarks in the [`MouseProc` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988(v=vs.85).aspx):

> This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**

Oh, and in case you don't want to use a dll, you can use the `WH_MOUSE_LL`, which is called in the context of your own application.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/872720/4928207

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the last thing you said is smth new for me. According to MSDN, "If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL". I thought that it says "if your application need to intercept the other application's messages then you need to use DLL". Am I wrong?

Comment: Not for every type of hook, look at the [remarks from f.e. WH_MOUSE_LL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: But yes, sadly the information about hooks is scattered around a bit, some info is on the generic page, some info is on the HookProc page.

Comment: Can you give me an example how can I write such interception without using DLL? I've tried to call it like this `HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouse_hook, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());` or like this `HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE, mouse_hook, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());` and it doesn't work

Comment: Also, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31698252/4928207) i posted a fully functional console app that hooks WH_KEYBOARD_LL, it should be trivial to change that to WH_MOUSE_LL.

Comment: @MarkJansen: better yet, since the OP wants to hook a specific window, use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the thread ID that the window belongs to.  Then the hook will only be for that one thread and not for all threads on the system.

Comment: Can I use `WH_MOUSE` instead of `WH_MOUSE_LL` without DLL? Is it possible?